# Why is this Float constant null when executing the static block?

Tags: java, static-initialization

The following code, when executed, prints `nitesh null` instead of the expected `nitesh 130`.
Why isn't `n` initialized before executing the static block?

```
class test
{
      static
      {
             System.out.println(test.str+"   "+test.n);
      }
      final static String str="nitesh";
      final static Float n=130f;
      public static void main(String []args)
      {
      }
}
```

Comment: [`This question should be closed because it is answered by JonSkeet`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13300/256679)

Answer (score 25):

`str` is a compile-time constant - `n` is not, because it's of type `Float`. If you change it to `final static float n = 130f` then you'll see the value in the static initialization block.

So currently, in the static initializer block, the value of `str` is actually being inlined - your code is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println("nitesh   "+test.n);
```

From [JLS section 15.28 (constant expressions)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28):

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following: [...]

`Float` is not a primitive type.

Additionally, even without the inlining, the constant variable `str` is initialized before any of the static initializer blocks are executed. From [section 12.4.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) (class initialization details):

> - ...
> - Then, initialize the static fields of C which are constant variables (§4.12.4, §8.3.2, §9.3.1).
> - ...
> - Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

Comment: @TAsk: No, that's in no way a shorter version of what I said. It's all to do with which variables are actually compile-time constants, whose values are inlined wherever they're used.

Comment: Oppss!! Agree.Need to spend more time With JavaDoc. _Thanks for the clarification._ (_By the way +10 for your answer_)

Comment: But Float is a primitive type http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @Arijit: No, `float` is a primitive type. `Float` is a wrapper type. They're different.

Comment: Does static initializer block run before `static final` variables are initialized?? Why? so surprised...

Comment: @ikh: See my quote: *constant* variables are initialized first, but then static initializers (including both static field initializers and  static initializer blocks) are run in textual order.

Comment: Which means that moving the static block after the declarations also fixes the issue.